# Why does subprocess timeout (or wait) not work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, popen

time.sleep() and popen.wait() don't work

Hi, I'm trying to write a programme that would restart the minecraft server after a certain time, I'm trying to do it by writing stop to the console, but I have the following problem: output commands such as MCser.stdin.write(b'say Restart after 30s\n') (code below) are executed simultaneously, ignoring time.sleep(), please help me to fix this.

```
import subprocess 
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

MCser = subprocess.Popen(["java.exe", "-Xms8024M", "-Xmx10096M", "-jar", "quilt-server-launch.jar"], stdout = PIPE, stdin = PIPE, stderr = PIPE)
MCser.stdin.write(b'say test\n')
MCser.stdin.write(b'say Restart after 30s\n')
time.sleep(20)
MCser.stdin.write(b'say Restart after 10s\n',)
time.sleep(10)
MCser.stdin.write(b'stop\n')
```

I also tried using Popen.wait, it also did not give any result, all commands are executed at the same time (code below)

```
import subprocess 
from subprocess import Popen
from subprocess import PIPE
from subprocess import TimeoutExpired

Zephyr = subprocess.Popen(["java.exe", "-Xms8024M", "-Xmx10096M", "-jar", "quilt-server-launch.jar"], stdout = PIPE, stdin = PIPE, stderr = PIPE)

try:
    Zephyr.wait(timeout=30)
except TimeoutExpired:
    Zephyr.stdin.write(b'say test\n')
    Zephyr.stdin.write(b'say Restart after 30s\n')

try:
    Zephyr.wait(timeout=20)
except TimeoutExpired:
    Zephyr.stdin.write(b'say Restart after 10s\n',)

try:
    Zephyr.wait(timeout=10)
except TimeoutExpired:
    Zephyr.stdin.write(b'stop\n')
```

Flush and others memory cleaning features also doesn't work

Comment: Asking to be sure did you import `time`  in your first script ?

Comment: Yeah (forgot to put it here)

Comment: Can you try adding \r before your \n like this `"b'say test\r\n'"`

Comment: Doesnt work too